# What program can I use to keep a window active in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

I've heard of a program called 'Caffine' that can stop Windows XP screen saver from activating - but I would like to keep a particular window 'alive' even if the workstation locks.

Comment: do you mean you want the workstation locked, but one application still running and available without unlocking it?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean, there are a number of "Run as Service" type programs but I have no experence with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, shouldn't a locked workstation can't be used at all unless you logon first? The Ease of Access apps could run even on logon screen, so I suppose there's a way, but it might involve creating a whole new program or planting a service. A better method would be to create some autohotkey script that prevent the user from leaving the program (either switching back if not activated or restricting the mouse movement area), or, if your particular apps support 'kiosk' mode, get that version